# Is Facebook SDK disabling event logging in development by default?

Tags: ios, facebook, analytics, facebook-ios-sdk

Seems like a pretty simple question that doesn't need stack overflow, but I can't seem to find a straight and clear answer to that.
I recently swapped from google analytics to FB analytics, following in a very precise way their setup tutorial.

It seems like events (for facebook analytics) aren't getting logged by default if the configuration is development, but I'm not sure, is it so?

I had a "dry run" option for google analytics, I was asking myself if there is such a thing for facebook sdk which I am not able to find, or if the dry run is enabled by default in debug mode, or I should do it manually by adding #if statements for the precompiler.